# Google sheets copying adjacent cells so they're stacked

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, concatenation, google-sheets-formula

I'm trying to create a cell in Google Sheets such that it is the value of one cell, a carriage return, and then the value of another cell. I want to be able to copy the resulting cell such that it can be pasted into a proprietary program that is expecting two cells vertically.

I'm able to create the cell using

```
=B3 & char(10) & B4
```

Which displays the values one on top of the other in the resulting cell.

The problem I have is that when I copy the contents of the new cell and paste it into my proprietary application, the carriage return doesn't copy, which was the whole point of making the cell to begin with.

Any ideas what I might do or perhaps there's a workaround I haven't thought of? It looks like there used to a web clipboard feature in Sheets but it's been discontinued.

Comment: how confident are you that the "Proprietary program" accepts carriage returns in it's input? Maybe it is getting rid of it on that end?

Comment: @MattKing I've been pasting vertical rows from Excel into the program for a while. In fact, the values in the vertical row are calculated and it pastes the calculated string instead of the formula

Comment: Could you share a sample of what you're trying to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

instead of your

```
=B3&CHAR(10)&B4
```

try:

```
={B3; B4}
```

Comment: Thanks for this, I wasn't aware I could make an array this way. It would work except I'm working with a large number of pairs in two columns and the result of this formula takes up two vertical cells, the second of which is the first line of the subsequent pair. I suppose I could write some code to free up a space between each of the pairs but that's not ideal, and I'm not sure the person I'm preparing this for would want to look at it that way

Comment: At the moment I did a really awkward workaround, which was to make a pivot table and force the columns into rows. Looking at it now I'm still not sure how it works or how I knew it might

Comment: Ok I just discovered the TRANSPOSE function, which does exactly what I want here - take an array of two vertical columns and turn it into an array of vertical pairs, such that the left column is the top value and the right column is the bottom value

Comment: Thanks for your help in getting me to think of this as an array!